# Select orders with certain item and certain line count

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select all the orders that have a certain item in it AND have 3 orderlines. So I have to combine a count with a where, but I struggle with it. Here is what I thought of, but it now counts the lines that have this item on it, which is always 1.

```
select * from ord
where ordnum in (select ol.ordnum
                 from ord o
                 join ord_line ol
                     on o.ordnum = ol.ordnum
                 where ol.prtnum in ('item_X'))
group by ordnum
having count (ordlin) = 3
```

Do I need to make 2 selects and combine the results? How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (The answer may be product specific.)

Comment: Your wording "I want to select all the orders" (`ord` i suppose) contraticts you code `select * from ord_line`. What exactly is needed?

Comment: It is much easier to answer when tables, sample data, expected results and range of DBMS supported are specified.

Comment: @NEER has answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HAVING gets orders with 3 items.
The WHERE makes sure that one of the itms is the one you need to include.

HTH.

```
Select O.OrdrNum, COUNT( OL.OrdNum )
FROM Ord O
INNER JOIN Ord_Line OL ON OL.ordnum = O.ordnum
WHERE O.OrdNum IN (SELECT OrdNum FROM Ord_Line WHERE prtnum = 'item_X')
GROUP BY O.OrdrNum
HAVING COUNT(OL.OrdNum) = 3
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks @AntDC

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    O.ordnum,
    COUNT(1)
FROM 
    ord O INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT tmp.ordnum FROM ord_line tmp
        WHERE
            tmp.prtnum in ('item_X'))
        GROUP BY ordnum HAVING COUNT(1) = 3

    ) A ON O.ordnum = A.ordnum
 GROUP BY O.ordnum
```

Comment: Missing keyword it says. I see in my OP i use select * from ord_line, but that meant to be select * from ord. I will change the OP.

Comment: ? Seems this solution will have EXACTLY the same problem as the original query - it will fail from the same reason.